# Call works only one-way , not both-ways

Tags: voip, freeswitch

I am trying to make an internal call from extension 1000 to 1001 and backwaards. 1000->1001 works and i can answer/hangup. 1001->1000 doesnt work. Can anyone assist me please ? Thank you. Here's the log:

```
freeswitch@ubuntu> 2015-10-24 19:54:48.252475 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel sofia/internal/1001@192.168.20.199 [81ce2ac0-dbf9-4102-9885-a0a4c6e0541e]
2015-10-24 19:54:48.272476 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:558 Processing 1001 <1001>->1000 in context default
2015-10-24 19:54:48.272476 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3631 Bound B-Leg: *1 execute_extension::dx XML features
2015-10-24 19:54:48.272476 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3631 Bound B-Leg: *2 record_session::/usr/local/freeswitch/recordings/1001.2015-10-24-19-54-48.wav
2015-10-24 19:54:48.272476 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3631 Bound B-Leg: *3 execute_extension::cf XML features
2015-10-24 19:54:48.272476 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3631 Bound B-Leg: *4 execute_extension::att_xfer XML features
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel sofia/internal/sip:1000@147.229.148.23:52888 [78eeebd6-be44-412b-8fe7-08ce94b21836]
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7112 Hangup sofia/internal/sip:1000@147.229.148.23:52888 [CS_CONSUME_MEDIA] [NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE]
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_originate.c:2707 Cannot create outgoing channel of type [user] cause: [NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE]
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [INFO] mod_dptools.c:3234 Originate Failed.  Cause: NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1632 Session 24 (sofia/internal/sip:1000@147.229.148.23:52888) Ended
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1636 Close Channel sofia/internal/sip:1000@147.229.148.23:52888 [CS_DESTROY]
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] sofia_media.c:92 Pre-Answer sofia/internal/1001@192.168.20.199!
2015-10-24 19:54:48.292436 [NOTICE] mod_dptools.c:1258 Channel [sofia/internal/1001@192.168.20.199] has been answered
2015-10-24 19:54:49.312660 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel loopback/app=voicemail:default 192.168.20.199 1000-a [ff3ba363-2c45-4466-b6d1-d05f507b882e]
2015-10-24 19:54:49.312660 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1051 Rename Channel loopback/app=voicemail:default 192.168.20.199 1000-a->loopback/voicemail-a [ff3ba363-2c45-4466-b6d1-d05f507b882e]
2015-10-24 19:54:49.312660 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel loopback/voicemail-b [15c11755-1891-4530-ac42-4f68b21c4abf]
2015-10-24 19:54:49.312660 [NOTICE] mod_loopback.c:947 Pre-Answer loopback/voicemail-a!
2015-10-24 19:54:49.312660 [NOTICE] mod_dptools.c:1293 Pre-Answer loopback/voicemail-b!
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] sofia.c:926 Hangup sofia/internal/1001@192.168.20.199 [CS_EXECUTE] [NORMAL_CLEARING]
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_bridge.c:751 Hangup loopback/voicemail-a [CS_EXCHANGE_MEDIA] [ORIGINATOR_CANCEL]
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] mod_loopback.c:553 Hangup loopback/voicemail-b [CS_EXECUTE] [ORIGINATOR_CANCEL]
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1632 Session 26 (loopback/voicemail-b) Ended
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1636 Close Channel loopback/voicemail-b [CS_DESTROY]
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1632 Session 23 (sofia/internal/1001@192.168.20.199) Ended
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1636 Close Channel sofia/internal/1001@192.168.20.199 [CS_DESTROY]
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1632 Session 25 (loopback/voicemail-a) Ended
2015-10-24 19:54:52.452289 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1636 Close Channel loopback/voicemail-a [CS_DESTROY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a firewall problem. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that user 1000 is registered when you call it? (You can list the registered users from cli).
Another possible reason might be that there are some special users in the 1001-1009 range. You might try using different usernames.
If still doesn't work, post some more detailed logs (you should increase the debug/log levels).